# Why warning when passing withTheme wrapped component to Route?

Tags: react-router-v4, styled-components

I get the following warning using `"react-router": "4.3.1"` and `"styled-components": "4.1.3"`

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
    in Route (created by Routes)
    in Routes (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Routes))
    in withRouter(Routes) (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(App))
    in withRouter(App) (created by StartPage)
    in div (created by ScrollToTop)
    in ScrollToTop (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(ScrollToTop))
    in withRouter(ScrollToTop) (created by StartPage)
    in ThemeProvider (created by StartPage)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (created by StartPage)
    in Provider (created by StartPage)
    in StartPage
```

This is my `Routes` class (with irrelevant parts removed):

```
interface RoutesProps extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {
}

class Routes extends React.Component<RoutesProps, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/otii/standard" component={OtiiStandard} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(Routes);
```

This the OtiiStandard class (again with most irrelevant parts removed):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled, { withTheme } from 'styled-components';

interface OtiiStandardProps {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    theme: any;
}

const ImageContainer = styled.div`
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
`;

const Center = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
`;

const SectionContainer2 = styled(SectionContainer)`
    margin-top: 38px;
`;

// tslint:disable:max-line-length

const OtiiStandard = (props: OtiiStandardProps) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Center>
                ....
            </Center>
        </>
    );
};

export default withTheme(OtiiStandard);
```

I can get the warning to go away in two different ways:

A)

Change the route to:

```
<Route path="/otii/standard" component={() => <OtiiStandard/>} />
```

B)

Do not wrap OtiiStandard with withTheme

```
export default OtiiStandard;
```

**Questions**

- Why does this warning appear? I have many other components that I have written the same way, that are also wrapped by `withTheme` that do not cause warnings?
- Am I fine changing the route to `<Route path="/otii/standard" component={() => <OtiiStandard/>} />` or does my code seem to have any problems?